# is there any way to make Custom Own regular expression for email, like i want to go with abc@xyz.com instead of abc@gmail.com.?

Tags: php, regex

Is there any way to make Custom own email **regular expression?**

Actually I want to create one registration form in p.h.p. and for email validation,

I want to make my own customized email regular expression.
For example,lets say I want to check that the given mail is
 `name-number@ves.ac.in`.

It should only accept email id that ends with `ves.ac.in` and should notify if given mail is not matching with expression. 
I did lot of experiment on:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$
```

but this expression but failed. please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: The regex that you show appears to (try to) validate generic email addresses, it doesn't restrict to `ves.ac.in`. You want to start with something like `^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@ves\.ac\.in$`.

Comment: `^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@ves\.ac\.in$`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To check for a particular domain e.g, (yahoo.com):

```
 regx =  /^[^@\s]+@yahoo\.com$/i;
 regx.test(input);
 //returns true if it matches
```

check this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6mw3/277/).

Comment: you can put your own domain.

Comment: I didn't point out about any domain. the `dot` in your regular expression matches any character not a literal `.` you should escape it  like `^[^@\s]+@yahoo\.com$`

Answer (score 1):

The right regex could be this: `^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@ves\.ac\.in$`

Here's a [regex-tester](https://regex101.com/r/qaqdmq/1)

Answer (score 0):

if you are validating with jQuery or javascript, then you can validate using

```
var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
if(!filter.test(email)){
 // add error here
}
```

Comment: This doesn't restrict to addresses ending in `ves.ac.in`.